# Trouble expressing general form of the plane equation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry, 3d

I have a task to convert a vector form of the plane equation to the general form. General form being $ax + by + cz + d = 0$.

This is the equation:

$\vec r = (2, 1, 3) + u(1, 0, 0) + v(-1, 1, 2)$

Now, the way were were thought was this: Express $x, y$ and $z$; express $u$ and $v$ in terms of $x, y$ and $z$ and then just put it all in one equation.

Here's the parametric form:

$x = 2 + u - v$

$y = 1     + v$

$z = 3         + 2v$

I tried to express $v$ in terms of $y$ and $z$, then I expressed $y$ in terms of $z$, but in the end I got a contradictory system. Namely, I got that $2 = 3$.

Can someone solve this step-by-step? It appears I got lost.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $<1,0,0>$ and $<-1,1,2>$ lie in the plane.

So now we can find a vector normal to plane, which would be:

$$\begin{align}\vec n &=\ <1,0,0>\times<-1,1,2>\\
&=\ <0,-2,1>
\end{align}$$

Now you have the equation as:
$$(\vec r -<2,1,3>)\cdot \vec n = 0$$
$$(<x,y,z>-<2,1,3>)\cdot \vec n = 0$$

Solving yields:

$$2y-z+1=0$$

Comment: One question - why did you write $(\vec r - <2, 1, 3>) \vec n$. Where did the $\vec r$ come from?

Comment: $r$ is position vector of point which is on plane. So a vector in plane would be **position vector of a point** minus **position vector of another point** on plane. Thats triangle law.

Comment: OK. And why is it equal to 0?

Comment: see, $\vec r-<2,1,3>$ is perpendicular to $\vec n$, so the dot product is zero.

Answer (score 0):

You need to eliminate $u$ and $v$, leaving you with an equation in $x$, $y$ and $z$.

$x = 2 + u - v$

$y = 1     + v$

$z = 3         + 2v$

Rewrite $v=y-1$ and substitute that into both the other equations:

$x = 2 + u - v \Rightarrow x=2+u-(1-y)\Rightarrow x-y-1=u$. In this case you can't eliminate $u$ but that isn't a problem because:

$z = 3         + 2v \Rightarrow z=3+2y-2 \Rightarrow 2y-z+1=0$ gives you the equation in the required format.

Note that $a=0$, $b=2$, $c=-1$, $d=1$

Comment: I think you made an arithmetic mistake in solving for $x$. In particular $-v$ is equal to $-y + 1$ and not $ -1 - y$. Anyhow, my question is, how do I know that solving for $z$ gives me my plane equation?

Comment: Fixed that. Thanks for spotting my error!

Comment: Could you adress my other question - "my question is, how do I know that solving for z gives me my plane equation?". To expand on that, how do I know to ignore $u$?